# SSRS Conditional Formatting with start date and end date being on the current day

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to implement conditional formatting where the background fill changes when the start date and end date is both the current day but it is defeating me.

Here is what I have:

```
=IIf(Fields!Adata.Value = "Ball","Yellow",nothing)

=IIF(Fields!Bdata.Value = "Sign","Yellow",nothing)

=IIF(Format(END_DATE.Value, "yyyyMMdd") = Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd"), 
"Yellow", nothing)
=IIF(Format(START_DATE.Value, "yyyyMMdd") = Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd"), 
"Yellow", Nothing)
```

How do I get these to work as one expression versus 4 separate expressions, having the 2 date expressions work together where they only trigger when the start date and end date are both equal to the current day.

Comment: You code has syntax errors, assuming END_DATE and STRT_DATE are parameters then they should be referenced as `Parameters!END_Date.Value` etc... Having said that logically your code reads, if Adata is "Ball" or BData is "Sign" or END_DATE is Today or STRT_DATE is Today then "Yellow" ELSE Nothing. IF this is incorrect, edit your question to explain what you actually want, include sample data with expected results too, that always help.

Comment: Take a look now @alan

Comment: It's still not clear what you actually what. What if Adata = Ball and the dates are not the same or are not today? What happens then? It's much easier for people who want to help you if you show some samples of data, combinations of the database columns and the parameters with the expected outcome from each combination. Also you have still not specified what END_DATE and STRT_DATE are, are they parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missing an AND, though as noted by Alan END_DATE and START_DATE look like they need something in front of them; Field!, Parameters! etc.:

```
=IIF(Fields!Adata.Value = "Ball","Yellow", IIF(Fields!Bdata.Value = "Sign","Yellow", IIF(((Format(END_DATE.Value, "yyyyMMdd") = Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd")) AND ((Format(START_DATE.Value, "yyyyMMdd") = Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd")))), "Yellow", nothing))))
```